# Where is Google App Engine data store on Windows 7?

Tags: google-app-engine

Where is the Google App Engine data store on Windows 7? The following answer to this question is for an earlier version of Windows, and the equivalent location on Windows 7 does not seem to contain the data store.

On my Windows machine the datastore file is stored in:
C:\Documents and Settings(yourusername)\Local Settings\Temp
It'll have a .datastore extension.

Answer (score 0):

This file has probably nothing to do with the App Engine Datastore.

On an App Engine development project, the local datastore is kept under the following path :

```
PATH_TO_WAR_FOLDER\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local-db.bin
```

In the same folder, you may find various files with short, cryptic names. Those are the blobs and Cloud Storage files that are stored on your computer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I don't recognize "PATH_TO_WAR_FOLDER\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local-db.bin" as anything that would tell me where to look for this on Windows 7.